# XML export in Excel fails: XML table is bound to a different XML map

Tags: excel, xml, mapping, export

### Initial situation

An existing Excel document with several sheets including formulas and VisualBasic macros.

### Steps to reproduce

1. A new sheet was added with a simple table (1 row, some columns) to be exported. The table cells were filled by VB macro.
2. An XML schema (XSD) had been imported [according to documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-xml-in-excel-f11faa7e-63ae-4166-b3ac-c9e9752a7d80), but no schema elements were mapped yet.
3. When trying to map the XML schema elements to the table, I always get the error message:

> The operation cannot be completed because the XML table is bound to a different XML map.

However, there is no other XML schema in the entire document at all.

4. Removing the XML schema and re-importing it doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to

1. remove the XML schema,
2. create a new sheet,
3. copy-paste the table into it,
4. import the XML schema again and
5. map the schema elements.

The following XML export was also working.